# Cómo repintar un ListView con un hilo dentro del evento DrawItem en c#

Tags: c#, listview

Quisiera saber cómo repintar un ListView con un hilo dentro del evento DrawItem.
Resumo el problema antes de exponerlo: Tengo un ListView donde se muestran logotipos como una imagen y su nombre como un string. Las imágenes no son ficheros que tenga en local, se obtienen de una lista de URL’s que hay que descargar. En cada momento la lista de URL’s es distinta por lo que ha de controlar las excepciones que se producen en la descarga. Una de las excepciones ha controlar es que el servidor no responda, por lo que he de controlar que el proceso de descarga no dure más de un par de segundos. Cero que la única manera de poder interrumpir la descarga pasados 2 segundos es con un hilo. Pues el problema es precisamente este, si no utilizo un hilo (es decir, no puedo parar la descarga, el proceso se puede convertir en eterno y la aplicación se queda bloqueada) no hay problema de repintado del ListView, pero si utilizo un hilo para controlar la descarga, si muevo con fuerza la rueda del ratón sobre el ListView, o muevo rápidamente la barra de desplazamiento del LisView, o se pulsa rápidamente las lechas de desplazamiento del teclado para posicionarse en el siguiente item del LisView, el evento DrawItem deja de producirse.
El evento DrawItem es:

```
private void ListViewLogos_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item as ImagenListViewItem;

    if (item.Bitmap == null)
    {
        DatosUrl datosUrl = Programa.ObtenerImagenDeURL(listaDeLogos.ElementAt(e.ItemIndex).stringlogo, 1);
        item.Bitmap = (Bitmap)Programa.RedimensionarImagen(datosUrl.imagen, anchoMiniatura, altoMiniatura);
    }

    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.Clip = new Region(e.Bounds);

    int w = Math.Min(anchoMiniatura, item.Bitmap.Width);
    int h = Math.Min(altoMiniatura, item.Bitmap.Height);
    int x = (anchoMiniatura - w) / 2;
    int y = e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - h) / 2;
    Rectangle dstRect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, item.Bitmap.Size);

    Rectangle rectanguloDelTexto = new Rectangle(new Point(anchoMiniatura, e.Bounds.Y + 2), new Size(e.Bounds.Width - anchoMiniatura, altoMiniatura));
    StringFormat formato = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip) { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near };

    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.MenuHighlight, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, this.Font, Brushes.White, rectanguloDelTexto, formato);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Green, rectanguloDelTexto, formato);
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(item.Bitmap, dstRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    e.Graphics.Clip = new Region();
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.ControlLight, e.Bounds);
}
```

Donde se ejecuta el hilo es en **DatosUrl datosUrl = Programa.ObtenerImagenDeURL(listaDeLogos.ElementAt(e.ItemIndex).stringlogo, 1);**:

```
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread = true)]

public static DatosUrl ObtenerImagenDeURL(string url, int indice)
{
    datosUrl.Resetear(url);

    ThreadStart delegado1 = new ThreadStart(Descargar);
    Thread hilo1 = new Thread(delegado1);
    hilo1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    {
        Interval = 2000
    };
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();

    hilo1.Start();
    while (hilo1.IsAlive)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();

        if (tiempoCumplido)
        {
            hilo1.Abort();
            datosUrl.error = "Excedido el tiempo de espera.";
            tiempoCumplido = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    timer.Stop();
    if (datosUrl.error != "") GestionarErrorDeDescarga(indice);
    MostrarResultadoDeLaDescarga(datosUrl);
    return datosUrl;
}
```

El Timer controla el tiempo de los 2 segundos:

```
private static bool tiempoCumplido = false;

private static void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tiempoCumplido = true;
}
```

Y el proceso que ejecuta el hilo, el método Descargar:

```
private static void Descargar()
{
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2");
        byte[] byteImage = client.DownloadData(datosUrl.url);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteImage);
        datosUrl.imagen = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        client.Dispose();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Excepcción capturada.", e);
        datosUrl.error = e.Message;
    }
}
```

Como he dicho ante, si quito el hilo y claro también el Timer, el repintado es correcto, pero **necesito poder matar el proceso Descargar**. El problema no se si está en el procesado de la cola de mensajes de Windows, es decir en la línea **Application.DoEvents()**; del while que se ejecuta mientras el hilo está vivo, porque, aunque el ListView está completamente en blanco, sin repitar, puedo pulsar sobre los “supuestos” ítems que no están visibles y el evento SelectedIndexChanged se produce, ya que muestro información del item en otros controles, pero el evento DrawItem no se produce. Y cuando se genera un evento del formulario, por ejemplo lo minimizo y lo restauro, entonces se produce el evento DrawItem y se repinta el LisView.
Bueno pues, haber si alguien me puede decir como he de poder hacer que se repinte el ListView sin prescindir del hilo que se ejecuta en el DrawItem. Muchas Gracias.

Explico más cosas. Los ítems los añado al ListView de esta manera:

```
private class ImagenListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    public Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
}

private void PonerCanalesEnElListView()
{
    Image imagen;

    ListViewLogosDelFichero.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        ListViewLogosDelFichero.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (Logo logo in listaDeLogos)
        {
            if (logo.stringlogo == "N/A" || logo.stringlogo == "") imagen = Resource.sinLogo;
            else imagen = null;
            ImagenListViewItem item = new ImagenListViewItem
            {
                Text = Convert.ToString(logo.indice + 1) + "\r\n" + logo.nombre,
                Bitmap = (Bitmap) imagen,
            };

            ListViewLogosDelFichero.Items.Add(item);
        }
        ListViewLogosDelFichero.EndUpdate();
    });
}
```

Como veis, el Bitmap de cada item del ListView no se descarga de internet cuando se añaden los item, les pongo una imagen de los recursos, o los pongo a null, para que cuando se repinten los item en evento DrawItem se descarguen si están a null. De esta manera los logos se van descargando según se visualicen en el ListView y así evitar que se genere un gran parón en la aplicación, si los descargo al poner los item en el ListView. La listaDeLogos puede tener más de 1000 logos si los descargo de internet al poner los item parece que la aplicación se ha bloqueado (hay que hacer 1000 descargas), al hacerlo en el evento DrawItem todo es fluido, porque solo se descargan unos 10 (si no se ha n descarado ya), que son los que se suelen visualizar en cada momento.

Comment: Debo aclararte que no he entendido 100% tu pregunta, pero creo haber visto algo similar hace muuuucho tiempo así que tampoco recuerdo bien el tema. Lo que creo que te pasa es que lo que se ejecuta en un `Thread` no puede cambiar un elemento de la interfaz gráfica directamente y la solución era colocar un paso intermedio (creo que se utilizaba uno `invoke` que llamaba al elemento) así que por ahí deberías buscar.  Por otro lado, podrías probar con tareas asíncronas `task` en lugar de hilos, para esto debes cambiar el WebClient por HttpClient y este en sus métodos asíncronos tiene un campo...

Comment: ... llamado `CancellationToken` que te permite termina la tarea con anticipación

Comment: Gracias Yussef por tu comentario. He probado lo que me dices de hacer asíncrona ObtenerImagenDeURL, pero como tengo Thread que llaman a esta función y métodos que abren formularios tras llamar a esta función, todo se ha vuelto caótico, y los hilos terminan sin tener que terminar los formularios se cierran solos y bueno las descargas de los logos, al utilizar HttpClient, se ralentizan una barbaridad. Una secuencia de descargas de logos que antes se hacía en 10 segundos ha pasado del orden de minutos. Por lo que no he podido comprobar si se corrige el repintado del ListView.

Answer (score 0):

he visto los comentarios y siguiendo mi experiencia de añadir campos en un listview usando thread por ejemplo requiere normalmente un invoke como dijo yussef lo del asíncrono no lo tengo tan claro, si es necesario, ya que lo uso solo en casos especificos. Te dejo un ejemplo que uso yo para interaccionar con los listview desde thread.

```
private void CheckListviewItems(string text)
    {
        //nota que no se asignan directamente pueden ir fuera del if
        if (listView1.InvokeRequired)//Mira si se requiere invocar normalmente si
       {
            //invocamos el listview
            listView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                //aquí va el codigo que interacciona directamente con el listview

            }));
        }
        else
        {
           //mismo código que interacciona el listview, pero por alguna razón no requiere en este momento invoke 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Gracias rexxarcat, pero no entiendo lo que he de hacer con tu función CheckListviewItems(string text).
Añado en mi pregunta el código que utilizo para añadir los item al ListView. (por favor mira lo que he explicado) …

Comment: … Bien, explicado esto, te digo que no entiendo que he de hacer con tu función, ¿tengo que usarla al poner los item?, ¿tengo que llamarla  en ObtenerImagenDeURL?, ¿en ListViewLogos_DrawItem?, ¿cómo se consigue con tu función que se genere el evento DrawItem, que se me deja de producir?.